# Is Caffe's reported accuracy reliable?

Tags: caffe, confusion-matrix

I recently tried to get the confusion matrix for one of my trained models, to see how precise it is.  I downloaded this script and fed my model. To my astonishment, the accuracy calculated by the script, is very different than the one, Caffe reports.

I have used [this script](https://gist.github.com/axel-angel/b2af7d980eb217a0af07) to calculate the confusion matrix, this however, reports the accuracy as well, **the problem is the accuracy reported by this script is way different that the one reported by Caffe!** For example Caffe reports the accuracy lets say for `CIFAR10`, as 92.34%, while, when the model is fed to the script to calculate confusion matrix and its accuracy, it results in for example something like 86.5%!

**Which one of these accuracies are the correct one, and can be reported in papers or compared with the results of other papers such as those [here](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Frodrigob.github.io%2Fare_we_there_yet%2Fbuild%2Fclassification_datasets_results.html%2343494641522d313030&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHlNXPmKuvC0R2w8MsWikjC8O3nuQ)** ?

I also saw something weird again, I trained two identical models, with only one difference, that being one used Xavier, and the other used `msra` for initialization. The first one reports an accuracy of 94.25 and the other reports 94.26 in Caffe. when these models are fed to the script I linked above, for confusion matrix computations. their accuracies were 89.2% and 87.4% respectively!

Is this normal? what is the cause for this? msra?

Are the accuracies reported by Caffe true and reliable?

PS: The accuracy in the script is calculated as ([complete script](https://gist.github.com/axel-angel/b2af7d980eb217a0af07)):

```
  for i, image, label in reader:
        image_caffe = image.reshape(1, *image.shape)
        out = net.forward_all(data=np.asarray([ image_caffe ]))
        plabel = int(out['prob'][0].argmax(axis=0))

        count += 1
        iscorrect = label == plabel
        correct += (1 if iscorrect else 0)
        matrix[(label, plabel)] += 1
        labels_set.update([label, plabel])

        if not iscorrect:
            print("\rError: i=%s, expected %i but predicted %i" \
                    % (i, label, plabel))

        sys.stdout.write("\rAccuracy: %.1f%%" % (100.*correct/count))
        sys.stdout.flush()

    print(", %i/%i corrects" % (correct, count))
```

Which imho is OK and correct. the number of correct predictions, divided by the total number of instances in the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. 
The reason for the mismatch between Caffe generated accuracy and the accuract generated by the script in question, was solely because of mean-subtraction, which was done in caffe, and not in the script. 
[This](https://gist.github.com/Coderx7/830ada70049ebbe7d7dc75101645b2f9) is the modified version of script which takes this into account and hopefully everything is just fine.

```
# Author: Axel Angel, copyright 2015, license GPLv3.
# added mean subtraction so that, the accuracy can be reported accurately just like caffe when doing a mean subtraction
# Seyyed Hossein Hasan Pour
# Coderx7@Gmail.com
# 7/3/2016 

import sys
import caffe
import numpy as np
import lmdb
import argparse
from collections import defaultdict

def flat_shape(x):
    "Returns x without singleton dimension, eg: (1,28,28) -> (28,28)"
    return x.reshape(filter(lambda s: s > 1, x.shape))

def lmdb_reader(fpath):
    import lmdb
    lmdb_env = lmdb.open(fpath)
    lmdb_txn = lmdb_env.begin()
    lmdb_cursor = lmdb_txn.cursor()

    for key, value in lmdb_cursor:
        datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
        datum.ParseFromString(value)
        label = int(datum.label)
        image = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum).astype(np.uint8)
        yield (key, flat_shape(image), label)

def leveldb_reader(fpath):
    import leveldb
    db = leveldb.LevelDB(fpath)

    for key, value in db.RangeIter():
        datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
        datum.ParseFromString(value)
        label = int(datum.label)
        image = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum).astype(np.uint8)
        yield (key, flat_shape(image), label)

def npz_reader(fpath):
    npz = np.load(fpath)

    xs = npz['arr_0']
    ls = npz['arr_1']

    for i, (x, l) in enumerate(np.array([ xs, ls ]).T):
        yield (i, x, l)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--proto', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--model', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--mean', type=str, required=True)
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('--lmdb', type=str, default=None)
    group.add_argument('--leveldb', type=str, default=None)
    group.add_argument('--npz', type=str, default=None)
    args = parser.parse_args()

# Extract mean from the mean image file
    mean_blobproto_new = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.BlobProto()
    f = open(args.mean, 'rb')
    mean_blobproto_new.ParseFromString(f.read())
    mean_image = caffe.io.blobproto_to_array(mean_blobproto_new)
    f.close()

    count = 0
    correct = 0
    matrix = defaultdict(int) # (real,pred) -> int
    labels_set = set()

   # CNN reconstruction and loading the trained weights 
    net = caffe.Net(args.proto, args.model, caffe.TEST)
    caffe.set_mode_cpu()
    print "args", vars(args)
    if args.lmdb != None:
        reader = lmdb_reader(args.lmdb)
    if args.leveldb != None:
        reader = leveldb_reader(args.leveldb)
    if args.npz != None:
        reader = npz_reader(args.npz)

    for i, image, label in reader:
        image_caffe = image.reshape(1, *image.shape)
        out = net.forward_all(data=np.asarray([ image_caffe ])- mean_image)
        plabel = int(out['prob'][0].argmax(axis=0))

        count += 1
        iscorrect = label == plabel
        correct += (1 if iscorrect else 0)
        matrix[(label, plabel)] += 1
        labels_set.update([label, plabel])

        if not iscorrect:
            print("\rError: i=%s, expected %i but predicted %i" \
                    % (i, label, plabel))

        sys.stdout.write("\rAccuracy: %.1f%%" % (100.*correct/count))
        sys.stdout.flush()

    print(", %i/%i corrects" % (correct, count))

    print ""
    print "Confusion matrix:"
    print "(r , p) | count"
    for l in labels_set:
        for pl in labels_set:
            print "(%i , %i) | %i" % (l, pl, matrix[(l,pl)])
```